# Pre-built shapes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, paintevent

As the title indicates, i try to use predefined shapes, but I don't find any module or class that's designed for that, i think Qt doesn't offer such possibility (i could be wrong), and everything should be done by hand by overriding the `paintEvent` function, so i decided to create my own shape (a line), the problem is that it doesn't display correctly when i apply the `setRenderHint` method :

---

```
// x1  y1  x2  y2 : are integers that change according to the geometry of the parent (QWidget)

void Line::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
   QPainter shape(this);

   shape.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); // <== Here

   QPen pen(Qt::black);
   forme.setPen(pen);

   shape.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

---

If I remove this functionality the shape looks ugly (in the diagonal), and if i keep it, the line drawn show a gradient :

[image: Image :]

The other problem is that i have to calculate each time the positioning of the line according to the geometry of my Widget.

---

**So my question is :** would it be possible to create shapes that do not depend on the `paintEvent` function ? Otherwise, are there any external library that offer pre-built shapes ?

Comment: Use Qt Graphics Framework

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: @Sergei Qt 5.14

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use QML rather than widgets. This seems very natural for the problem that you have described. QML provides a component *Shape* that can easily and conveniently render different shapes. Create one and add *ShapePath* children to render actual shapes.

Qt by itself does not provide large number of shapes (only rectangles, lines and ellipses), but it does support large subset of [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) which means that you can build any library of shapes to your heart content as SVG files and load those. The QML might look like this

```
Shape
{
    id: root

    ShapePath  {
         id: selection
         fillColor: "#EBF2F7"
         strokeWidth: 5
         strokeColor: "#0100ADEF"

         PathSvg {
             path: "L 150 50 L 100 150 z" // your path goes here 
         }     
     }
}
```

Here's a sample component created in Qt 5.12 from SVG graphics file drawn in graphic editor and rendered using Shape components. It's vector graphics, fully resizable and fully interactive in real app (can pick individual teeth, disable some of them etc.). Each tooth in this component is a Shape.

[image: Sample widget created from SVG graphics]

In Qt 5.12 creating custom widgets / graphics with paintEvent() is likely not the best option, but if you want to stick with it, there's a nice class QSvgRenderer that can render SVG in pretty much the same way that you used to draw a line.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are heavy and using them for individual shapes is not useful. You want to have a single widget that can iterate the list of shapes and paint them. Such widgets exist: QGraphicsSceneView shows what’s inside a QGraphicsScene. You may wish to start there.